# Headset combo jack adapter

Tags: audio, headset, audio-adapters

I have an HP Envy 15t laptop computer. I recently purchased the [Creative Fatal1ty](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826158082) headset for my computer, and because the HP Envy only has a headphone/microphone combo jack I purchased [this adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2W02KP1771).

I can hear sound through the headphones but the microphone is not working. I tested the microphone on a different computer with two separate audio jacks so I know that it works, and I tried the adapter on my iPod and my cell phone and it still did not work. Did I buy the wrong adapter, and if so, what should I buy?

Comment: I guess you should include product names and images into the question, links tend to broke over time.

Comment: Maybe it just split it into right and left channel? Could you check it?